# how to parse the values in {0x33,0x00,0x56,0x08,0x22,0x11} using python

Tags: python, hex

I want to parse and use individual value in `{0x33,0x44,0x56,0x88,0x22,0x11}`  using python

I tried the following code

```
dict = {0x33,0x00,0x56,0x08,0x22,0x11};

for item in dict:
    print"value:",hex(item);
```

Getting response as

```
value: 0x0
value: 0x22
value: 0x8
value: 0x11
value: 0x33
value: 0x56
```

How ever I need the answer as below

```
value: 0x33
value: 0x00
value: 0x56
value: 0x08
value: 0x22
value: 0x11
```

Comment: Thats not a dict, that's a set

Comment: Is the ordering a problem? Sets are unordered. If you change your `{}` to `[]`, you will have a list, which is ordered.

Comment: I am getting input as like this {0x33,0x00,0x56,0x08,0x22,0x11}, i want to parse them in same order

Comment: @user10494297 well then, mine???

Comment: If you're receiving them as a set, then you've already lost the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

thanks all

l=(0x33,0x00,0x56,0x08,0x22,0x11)

for item in l:
  print"value:0x%02X"%item;

result:

value:0x33
value:0x00
value:0x56
value:0x08
value:0x22
value:0x11

Answer (score 1):

Its because it's not a dict, it's a set, so set's are unordered so try tuple or list, like:

```
l=[0x33,0x00,0x56,0x08,0x22,0x11]
```

Or:

```
l=(0x33,0x00,0x56,0x08,0x22,0x11)
```

Sets are not ordered, so the output will be ordered in a way that is the random order of the set

So end will be:

```
for item in l:
    print "value:0x%02X"%item
```

Comment: a set is not ordered , so  the output cannot be ordered

Comment: @ U9-Forward  with above i am getting like thisvalue: 0x33
value: 0x0
value: 0x56
value: 0x8
value: 0x22
value: 0x11

Comment: @U9-Forward I need all elements as 2 numbers like 0x33,0x56 .. not like 0x8

Comment: @user10494297 Now?

Comment: @U9-Forward - i am getting values in order, but I need like 0x08, but where ever 1st nibble is zero it is skipping that. I need format as byte like 2 nibbles.

Comment: @user10494297 Nice Point

Comment: @user10494297 You know that's same with set

Comment: @U9-Forward - what is the solution to have format properly

Comment: @user10494297 so what now